# multiple matching conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to filter results based on matching keywords.  This part I have successfully been able to implement.  However, there is a need to make this match some exclusively and others inclusively.  For instance, if a user selected "large" and "shirt", the product will need to match those exclusively.  But the user might want to see them in red, green, and blue (inclusively).  How can I make that happen?  Below is the basic concept, but the UNION does not appear to work:

```
SELECT id
FROM Filters
WHERE disabled = '0' AND filter IN ('large','shirt')
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(filter) = 2

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT id
FROM Filters
WHERE disabled = '0' AND filter IN ('red','green','blue') 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(filter) > 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating your own keyword?

Comment: @Arnaud UNION DISTINCT is actually the default operation if the 'ALL' keyword is not included.  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: @Eric yes, the filters will be dynamic.  I can handle that, I just don't know the overall structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you should be able to use an aggregated query with a `HAVING BY` clause that implements the logic using conditional aggregation.

Consider the below query:

```
SELECT id
FROM Filters
GROUP BY id
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN filter = 'large' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN filter = 'shirt' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN filter IN ('red','green','blue') THEN 1 END) = 1
```

**Details:**

This aggregated condition ensures that this `id` has a record where `filter = 'large'`:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN filter = 'large' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

This checks that this `id` has a record where `filter = 'shirt'`:

```
    MAX(CASE WHEN filter = 'shirt' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

And this checks that at least one of the 3 colors is available:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN filter IN ('red','green','blue') THEN 1 END) = 1
```

You should be able to adapt the logic to your exact requirements if needed.

Comment: I applied the syntax as shown above, but it seems to show only a single record no matter what inclusive filters are applied.  Any thoughts?  I did additionally add in "WHERE disabled='0'" too.  But that shouldn't affect it right?

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to add in the 'GROUP BY id'.  I am now getting better results, but If I select 'purple and teal', the results list are the same.  It's like it's matching just the first two conditions, but none of the inclusive.  Is it possible to add a 'HAVING COUNT(filter) > 1' as part of the MAX() statement?

Comment: @user1646428: the above query selects: large **and** shirt **and (** red *or* green *or* blue **)**... This demonstrates the logic, with data corresponding to your question. You should be able to adapt this for other combinations of *and/or* filters...

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with my filters listing.  After I corrected that, this worked like a charm!  Thanks GMB!  +1 for simplicity